# Drupal image gallery

Tags: drupal, field, image-gallery

I'm trying to create an image gallery in Drupal 7 and found this on the net: http://megadrupal.com/blog/creating-an-image-gallery-in-drupal-7 whixch seems all to be nice but after step 5, coding my template, I clear the cache and reload my page and I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 3 of /home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/sites/all/themes/marinelli/templates/node--gallery.tpl.php).
```

I looked through all the field values but I can't figure out what 'und' should belong to, can anyone be of help here? I appreciate every input, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First forgive my english! :)

Anyway...just yesterday i have read the same guide for my gallery site.

The notice that php return you is because maybe you have created a gallery without image inside:

Chenge the code using this:

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="node-gallery">
<?php
    if(!empty($node->field_img)){ // check if there are images
    $imgcount = count($node->field_img['und']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $imgcount; $i++) {
    $image_uri = $node->field_img['und'][$i]['uri'];
        // url
        $masthead_raw = image_style_url('gallery-thumb', $image_uri);
?>
  <a href="<?php print file_create_url($node->field_img['und'][$i]['uri']); ?>" rel="group-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="fancybox">
    <img class="image<?php print ($i + 1);?>" src="<?php print $masthead_raw; ?>" />
  </a>
<?php }
    } // endif
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you're attempting to check for an empty field.

if it had value it's structure would be something like below, ($node->field_img['und'])

```
[field_img] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => VALUE

                    )

            )

    )
```

But since it doesn't have a value, its structure is:

```
[field_img] => Array ()
```